# How can I make javascript fancy fading effects?

Tags: javascript, web

I was looking throught a website (http://www.mangore.com/) and I saw its giant slideshow on top of the page. I was intrested in knowing how is that fancy crossfading effect between images made. It seems that it is not  JavaScript built in feature. Can someone help me?

Comment: There are many javascrpit libraries that provide fade in/out functions, [they aren't hard to write yourself](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/01/javascript-fade-in-out/). Cross–fading is just adjusting the transparency of one image over another using either CSS rules or element style properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see something you like on a website, try inspecting the source code to see how they do it.

In this case, you'll notice that they use the DDSlider Jquery Library: http://codecanyon.net/item/ddslider-10-transitions-inline-content-support/10479